# SSRS lookup skipping rows not picking up values

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have lookup expression to compare two datasets, the lookup is missing certain rows. Some rows in Totaldownload in DataSetCount have value of that data , but lookup  is skipping. Some rows are lookup correctly why some were skipped. I am not sure if anyone has encountered this problem before where lookup is just returning blank to some rows in the column. please see image below ....

[image]

```
 =IIF(IsNothing(
Lookup(Cstr(Fields!REG.Value) & Format(CDate(Fields!FL_DATE.Value), "yyyy-MM-dd"), Cstr(Fields!REGISTER.Value) & Format(Cdate(Fields!Flightdate.Value), "yyyy-MM-dd"), Fields!TOTALDOWNLOAD.Value, "DataSetCount")), "Missing", 
Lookup(Cstr(Fields!REG.Value) & Format(CDate(Fields!FL_DATE.Value), "yyyy-MM-dd"), Cstr(Fields!REGISTER.Value) & Format(Cdate(Fields!Flightdate.Value), "yyyy-MM-dd"), Fields!TOTALDOWNLOAD.Value, "DataSetCount"))
```

Comment: That snippet of code isn't likeley to help anyone. You need to be a bit more specific.

Comment: I have put screenshot on it to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. Lookup does not like string and date together. I have to usse another column that is serial(number data type) to replace the register or REG. And all is now working....